# Indian currency symbol in SAS

Tags: sas

Can someone please let me know how can I use Indian currency symbol in SAS program?

Like we do for dollar as below

```
format Salary :dollar8.;
```

Comment: You can make your own custom icon. Have a study on [https://icomoon.io/](https://icomoon.io/)

Comment: I don't know about `SAS` but if you are just looking for a way to type out INR symbol, you could try this on Windows: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/indian-currency-rupee-symbol

Comment: thanks but I don't think any of the above ones shall work out for me

Comment: What have you tried?  Did you look at PICTURE statement in PROC FORMAT?

Answer (score 1):

A similar format can be built like this:

```
%let inr=%sysfunc(unicode(\u20B9));  

proc format;
  picture rupee 
    low - <0 = '00,000,000,000,009.99)' (prefix="(&inr")
    0 - high = '00,000,000,000,009.99 ' (prefix="&inr")
  ;
run;
```

Which, applied as follows:

```
data test;
  format x rupee.;
  x=34341.12;       output;
  x=-12343452435.44;output;
  x=0;              output;
run;
```

Gives:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Using ASCII in HTML**

```
<p>Rupee sign: &#8377;</p>
```

**Using UNICODE character in HTML**

```
<p>Rupee sign: &#x20B9;</p>
```

**Using CSS**

```
<style>
.inr-sign::before{
content:"\20B9";
}
// Or use with ::after
.inr-sign::after{
content:"\20B9";
}
</style>

<span class="inr-sign"></span>
```

**Using Font Awesome**

The icon name for rupee symbol is “fa-rupee-sign”

```
<i class="fas fa-rupee-sign"></i>
```

**More Options**

**Encoding**

```
HTML Entity: &#8377; 
HTML Entity (hex): &#x20B9; 
URL Escape Code: %E2%82%B9 
UTF-8 (hex): 0xE2 0x82 0xB9 
UTF-8 (binary): 11100010:10000010:10111001 
UTF-16: 0x20B9 
UTF-32: 0x000020B9
```

**Source Code**

```
C, C++, and Java: "\u20B9" 
CSS Code: \20B9 
JavaScript: "\u20B9" 
Perl: \x{20B9} 
Python 2: u"\u20B9" 
Python 3: \u20B9 
Ruby: \u{20B9}
```